# FullScreen DialogFragment doesn't fit the screen

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I am trying to make a dialog fragment to fit screen size, but the problem is that i am getting this result: [MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZRmt.png) 
[DialogScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic9cC.png)

As you see the dialog doesn't fit well inside the activity, I have tried a lot of things without any luck.
That's the way I am calling the dialog:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            EventDialog newFragment = new EventDialog();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            transaction.add(android.R.id.content, newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
```

And This is the dialog fragment class:

```
public class EventDialog extends DialogFragment {

public static final String TAG = "Event";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_dialog_layout, container, false);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("New Event");

    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close_white_24dp);
    }
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return rootView;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    return dialog;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.event_dialog_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_save) {
        // handle confirmation button click here
        return true;
    } else if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        // handle close button click here
        dismiss();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is the layout xml file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your content here" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

My goal is to make a full screen material design dialog

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In onResume() in your Eventdialog class you can set the height and width of the fragment like this -

```
 public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.width = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(params);



    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_dialog_layout, container, false);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("New Event");

    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close_white_24dp);
    }
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: when adding the on resume function my app crashes, I have tried to put it also inside the on create and but it didn't work, still thanks :)

Comment: what is the error... you can see it by clicking the android monitor at the bottom of the androidstudio. Remember this is the overrided function.. i have updated my answer...for refernce

Comment: It says : 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window android.app.Dialog.getWindow()' on a null object reference',
this is why i have tried to put it inside the onCreateDialog but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

did you tried putting style to your dialog fragment

```
EventDialog dialog = new EventDialog();
dialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), EventDialog.class.getName());
```

Comment: It makes the dialog look old, and in general it shows an error while trying DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE as a second parameter